# C# how to process a list

Tags: c#, list, function

Below is the code of a program I am trying to create to restart applications.  I've tried several different ways to make it work, researched Google and Stackoverflow about "Lists" but I'm either not understanding or not getting what I need.  "RestartData" is a .cs file that stores the properties and program.cs is the only other part of the program.  This is the main portion.

The problem area I have is at the proecessRestartList function.  I want to to go through the list (foreach) and check to see what the LastRestartTime is and if it is greater that RestartInterval, kill the process and restart it.  My problem is not knowing for certain how to actually write the syntax to make the function processRestartList actually do that.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class RestartData
    {
        public string ProgramLocation { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public int RestarInterval { get; set; }
        public bool RestartIfRunning { get; set; }
        public string ProgramServer { get; set; }
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastRestartTime { get; set; }
    }

 namespace ApplicationWatcher
    {
        public class RestartApplicationTask
        {
            public Int32 SleepInterval { get; set; }
            public String Status { get; set; }
            public String Error { get; set; }
            public bool Stopping { get; set; }
            public static log4net.ILog log { get; set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            Stopping = false;
            Error = "";
            Status = "Starting";
            if (SleepInterval == 0)
            {
                SleepInterval = 3600;
            }

            //make sure there is a logger
            if (log == null)
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4net"])));

                log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            }


            //This calls a method within the class. The name of the class is not needed, but the list and name of list is needed.
            List<RestartData> restartWorkList = AppRestartList();

            try
            {
                processRestartList(restartWorkList);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Replace with logging
                log.Info("Error: could not process " + restartWorkList);
            }
        }

        public static Happy.Common.HappyTools.DB GetCurrentlyRunningApplications(bool Active)
        {

        String qry= "SELECT ProgramLocation, Active, RestartIfRunning FROM any_database.dbo.AppWatcher WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Active = 1";
        //qry = qry.Replace("<Active>", Active.ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, (SqlConnection)DB.MakeConnection("any_database"));
        DataTable dt;

        Happy.Common.HappyTools.DB returnValue = new Happy.Common.HappyTools.DB();
        try
        {
            dt = DB.ExecuteTable(cmd, "any_database");

            DataRow thisRow = dt.Rows[0];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //do something
        }
        finally { }
        return returnValue;
        }

        static List<RestartData> AppRestartList()
        {
            List<RestartData> restartDatas = new List<RestartData>();

            //Don't need to create a new instance but does need to be assigned to at least null
            RestartData restartData = null;

            //This is an actual SQL Query that would be the same as in a SQL manager.
            string sqlQuery = "Select RestartTime, ProgramLocation, LastRestartTime, RestartInterval, ProgramServer, RestartIfRunning, ProcessName from dbo.AppWatcher where active=1;";

            //execute sql query
            //execute database reader
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, (SqlConnection)DB.MakeConnection("any_database"));
            DataTable dt;  



            command.Connection.Open();

            dt = DB.ExecuteTable(command, "any_database");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //move stuff from reader into log data, and exp
                //not RestartData restartData = new RestartData();  The RestartData() method is already declared
                restartData = new RestartData();
                restartData.ProgramLocation = Misc.NullSafeString(row["programLocation"]);
                //restartData.Active = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["active"]);
                restartData.RestarInterval = Misc.NullSafeInt(row["restartInterval"]);
                restartData.RestartIfRunning = Misc.NullSafeBool(row["restartIfRunning"]);
                restartData.ProcessName = Misc.NullSafeString(row["processName"]);
                restartData.LastRestartTime = Misc.NullSafeDateTime(row["lastRestartTime"]);

                //add restartData to list
                restartDatas.Add(restartData);

            }
            return restartDatas;
        }

        static void processRestartList(List<RestartData>restartJob)
        {    


            //i represents all the properties in LogData
            **foreach(RestartData i in restartJob)
            {
                if (i <= RestartData())
                {
                    i.LastRestartTime.AddHours(-1);
                }

            }**
         }     
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to iterate through the list and check if the LastRestartTime is greater that whatever it is set for

Comment: It would be good to make `RestartInterval` as `TimeSpan`. You can do something like `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(someNumber)` to easily create a time interval of a specific unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like the below. Assuming `RestartInterval` represents hours.

```
// Check what LastRestartTime is and if it is greater that RestartInterval, kill the process and restart it.
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; // Keep DateTime static.
foreach(RestartData restartData in restartJob)
{
    if (dt >= restartData.LastRestartTime.AddHours(restartData.RestarInterval))
    {
        restartData.LastRestartTime = dt;
        // restart process
    }
}
```

Comment: See [my comment to L.B's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788602/c-sharp-how-to-process-a-list#comment32966943_21788738) about things implementers should be aware of when using `DateTime.Now` inside a loop.

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right path.  I just wasn't sure how to make that work.

Comment: I've removed the minus as I got my logic mixed up. @ScottChamberlain, edited.

Answer (score 1):

The unit for `RestarInterval` is not clear, So i assumed `seconds`. If it it something different, change `TotalSeconds` accordingly (TotalMinutes, TotalHours etc.).

```
foreach(var data in restartJob.Where(x=> DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.LastRestartTime).TotalSeconds > x.RestarInterval))
{
    //kill
}
```

Comment: Having `DateTime.Now` inside the foreach loop there is some side effects you do need to be aware of. The time you will be comparing to will "move with you" as you process items, it may not matter much for a quick loop like this but if this is used for a loop that could take a long time to process depending on which behavior you want you may want to move it outside of the loop to `var now = DateTime.Now` and use `now.Subtract.(...` inside the loop. (this is more directed at future readers, not at the poster of the answer)